# Swift 3: How to do string ranges?

Tags: swift

Last night I had to convert my Swift 2.3 code to Swift 3.0 and my code is a mess after the conversion. 
In Swift 2.3 I had the following code:

```
let maxChar = 40;
let val = "some long string";
var startRange = val.startIndex;
var endRange = val.startIndex.advancedBy(maxChar, limit: val.endIndex);
let index = val.rangeOfString(" ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.BackwardsSearch , range: startRange...endRange , locale: nil)?.startIndex;
```

Xcode converted my code to this which doesn't work:

```
let maxChar = 40;
let val = "some long string";
var startRange = val.startIndex;
var endRange = val.characters.index(val.startIndex, offsetBy: maxChar, limitedBy: val.endIndex);
let index = val.range(of: " ", options: NSString.CompareOptions.backwards , range: startRange...endRange , locale: nil)?.lowerBound
```

The error is in the parameter `range` in `val.rage`, saying *No '...' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Range?'*.

I tried using `Range(startRange...endRange)` as suggestd in the docs but I'm getting en error saying: *connot invoke initiliazer for type ClosedRange<_> with an arguement list of type (ClosedRange)*. Seems like I'm missing something fundametnal.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: So you are looking for the last space?

Comment: This will be in a loop to chop the long string into smaller sections.

Comment: Right, you'll need to adapt my answer below, but it will definitely get you started. (I still don't understand what you're really doing, since you can just split the string on space characters in one move if that's your goal.)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I tried a different method but it didn't work for me so I had to do it in a complicated way. Is there a specific function for that?

Comment: You mean `split`?

Comment: Alternately: let parts = textString.components(separatedBy: " ");

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: splitting a very long string into sections and each section should be max 40 characters. I enter a new line where I find the nearest space.

Comment: @AliM Why not split by spaces and then recombine into sections?

Comment: Also I don't quite grasp why you start at the _end_ and do a _backwards_ search. What's that supposed to get you? If I were you, in future, I'd pose the _real_ problem you're trying to solve as your question, not some subproblem that might not be the right way of going about things at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: the fundamental thing you are missing is that a closed range is now different from a range. So, change `startRange...endRange` to `startRange..<endRange`.

In more detail, here's an abbreviated version of your code (without the `maxChar` part):

```
let val = "some long string";
var startRange = val.startIndex;
var endRange = val.endIndex;
let index = val.range(
    of: " ", options: .backwards, range: startRange..<endRange)?.lowerBound
// 9
```

Now you can use that as a basis to restore your actual desired functionality.

---

However, if all you want to do is split the string, then reinventing the wheel is kind of silly:

```
let arr = "hey ho ha".characters.split(separator:" ").map{String($0)}
arr // ["hey", "ho", "ha"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now! Do you mind if I ask why it was complaining about ... ?

Comment: Did you read my answer???? A closed range is not a range. That's the first thing I said.

Comment: So I have to add one to the endRange in order to include the last character in the range, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But you'll find that's very easy to adjust for. After all, the string's own `endRange` is _already_ out of bounds; you _cannot_ include it!

Comment: I just added a demo of how to use `split`. This could save you a lot of work. :)